# How to change the style of facebook comments from dark to light

Tags: facebook, styling, facebook-social-plugins

My comments FB thingo on this page: http://www.kashgar.com.au/articles/RSVP-Sydney-Event-Showcase-Exhibition is showing as the dark style. But my tag doesn't have the style in there as dark, so I don't know why this is happening.

I've tried `colorscheme="light"` and this does nothing.

Any ideas? I've also tried making the background white of the fb::comments. Still no help there.

What am i doing wrong here?

```
<fb:comments href="http://www.kashgar.com.au/articles/RSVP-Sydney-Event-Showcase-Exhibition" num_posts="5" width="630"></fb:comments>
```

Comment: What can i do to improve this question?

Comment: Actually, looking at DOM snapshot shows `<fb:comments colorscheme="dark" href=...`, so you *do* have the style set. Looking at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ *light* style is the default, so I believe you should check your source for the `style` tag being set. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try colorscheme='dark' which means FB will operate against a dark background. If you don't specify a colorscheme, then the default is 'light' which is the scheme used on your site.

I know you're already aware of it but it bears repeating that you can use the facebook configurator on FB to help with stylistic and other choices:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/